Rape and revenge movie about a woman going after a gang
I saw some movies in the 90's, now I had forgotten the title and the VHS-store where I rent the tapes is closed of course.
The movie is about a woman, she's going to a little American country for work reasons and meets her old father and pub, she's going in a pub-bar where she is molested by some villainous men (including a young boy, who isn't bad) and she reacts by hitting her molesters.
The molester then go at night to her house and raped her, the young boy dislikes this and try to escape but is killed by the villains' leader with a gun, the villains' leader is a man with a mustache who also kills the old parents of the woman when they return at home.
The day after she plans her revenge, kills one of the gang members with Molotov bottle (he's the bartender) then the other two (I don't remember how), and finally the man with the mustache who works as a butcher. Someone know the title?
Country: USA
Release time: 1988-92
Format: VHS
P.S. It's not "I spit on your grave"

You're looking for the cult film Naked Vengeance from 1985.

Carla Harris, a beautiful but not so successful actress from L.A., witnesses how her husband is tragically killed in an attempt to save a woman from her male attacker. She travels to her parents' home in a small town in the mountains to get some rest only to be repeatedly harassed by redneck locals and a teenager. The local sheriff refuses to help and so it all ends up in a gang rape and with Carla's parents shot dead. Carla survives and escapes from the mental hospital to seek bloody revenge.

The gang leader is a butcher and they shoot the teenager dead when he wants to go to the police. Here's the trailer (I won't embed it here since it's a bit graphic).
